# Is the key in AES algorithm public or private?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

It may not be the right place to ask this question but actually I have looked alot on the internet to find this anwser but I couldnt. I just want to know if the key in the AES public or private ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the case of AES we're usually talking about a *secret* key and never about a private or public key in order to distinguish from public-key crypto.

Answer (score 5):

AES is a *symmetric* encryption method so there is only one key, which should be known to both ends of the conversation.

Suffice to say, that means it should be a *private* key since anyone with the (single) key can decrypt your messages or fake messages coming from you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually this is what I was thinking but I want to know more. For example, now I have a software that encrypts vedios applying AES algorithm. So when I encrypt the vedio I just need to add a password and when the recipent gets the encrypted vedio, he needs the same password that I encrypted the video with. so what is the password here? and where is the public key?

Comment: @Ali.bu, there *is* no public key. AES is not suitable for public key crypto. Unless both parties already know the key, you'll need to find another method. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography for example. You can try to send the key separately via some *other* pathway but this has its own issues.

Comment: That means the software that I have now can not be used for network transmission? is it ?@paxdiablo

Comment: For a better idea, this is the link of the software that I am using [http://www.gilisoft.com/product-free-video-encryptor.htm]

Comment: I would say it cannot be used for secure transmission in the way you're attempting to use it. AES is actually quite secure but not if the keys become known to anyone not authorised.

Comment: Ok now I understand. Do you recommend any software (tools) that encrypts vedios (or media) applying AES algorithm for network transmission? @paxdiablo

Comment: Not really, I've never had a need to do this for videos and it sounds like you want an all-in-one video player with security. I would just tell anyone wanting it to supply their public key (using asymmetric method) which you use to encrypt the video file itself before sending it. Then the recipient decrypts with their private key, and no-one else, other than NSA-type organisations :-), can get at it. That's the general way of doing it but it's not really integrated. Uv gb zl sevraqf ng AFN, lbh qb n jbaqreshy wbo. <- That should keep them busy :-)

Comment: Ok that is great, I really appreciate your help mate. Many thanks !!